# How to draw a line from the center of a trapezium to the top and bottom surfaces? Using the M.north or M.south is ineffective in this case

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: The image I have right now]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % improve math presentation
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\def\TrLeangle{60}
\def\TrRiangle{120}

\begin{tikzpicture}[W/.style={trapezium,draw,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.3,minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm,trapezium left angle=\TrLeangle, trapezium right angle=\TrRiangle,thin,trapezium stretches=false},
axis/.style={densely dashed,gray,font=\small},
force/.style={>=latex,draw=blue,fill=blue},>=Triangle]

            \node[W] (W) {};
            \draw [->,dashed,thick](W.center) -- (1.0,2) node[right] {$\boldsymbol{y}$};%make do solution to get the desired result
            \draw [->,ultra thick,red](W.center) -- (W.north) node[above {$+y$};%problem line
            \draw [->,dashed,thick](W.center) -- ++(0,2) node[above right,rotate=0] {$\boldsymbol{z}$};
            \draw [->,dashed,thick](W.center) -- ++(3,0) node[right,rotate=0] {$\boldsymbol{x}$};
      
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The above is the code snippet of the tikz diagram I am trying to produce. Basically, I want a line that goes along the y axis(instead of the +y axis) and terminates on the "top" side of the parallelogram. Normally for a rectangle using M.north works just as well as M.east and M.west. But over here for the parallelogram, the same command fails. Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % improve math presentation

\begin{document}


\def\TrLeangle{60}
\def\TrRiangle{120}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    W/.style={trapezium, draw, fill=gray, fill opacity=0.3,
        minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm, 
        trapezium left angle=\TrLeangle, trapezium right angle=\TrRiangle,
        thin, trapezium stretches=false},
    axis/.style={densely dashed,gray,font=\small},
    force/.style={>=latex,draw=blue,fill=blue},>=Triangle]

            \node[W] (W) {};
            \draw[->,red] (W.center)--(W.top side);
            \draw[->,red] (W.center)--(W.right side);
            
%            \draw [->,dashed,thick](W.center) -- (1.0,2) node[right] {$\boldsymbol{y}$};%make do solution to get the desired result
%            \draw [->,ultra thick,red](W.center) -- (W.north) node[above] {$+y$};%problem line
%            \draw [->,dashed,thick](W.center) -- ++(0,2) node[above right,rotate=0] {$\boldsymbol{z}$};
%            \draw [->,dashed,thick](W.center) -- ++(3,0) node[right,rotate=0] {$\boldsymbol{x}$};
      
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And with `calc` library, you can even do better (more like your example picture): `\draw[->,red,dashed] (W.center)--($(W.top side)!-0.5!(W.center)$) node [above right] {$y$};
            \draw[->,red,dashed] (W.center)--($(W.right side)!-0.5!(W.center)$) node [right] {$x$};`